# MGTwitterEngine's sendUpdate inReplyTo not actually replying to a tweet

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, mgtwitterengine

The MGTwitterEngine's sendUpdate with the inReplyTo parameter is not actually replying to a tweet and is instead tweeting a new one!

I faced the long long value problem as discussed in the forums, but I fixed that and the tweetID remains constant across. But whenever I reply to a tweet, when I check the twitter page, I'd have just tweeted a new one, instead of a reply.

Please do let me know what I can do to fix this problem!

Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: have you found answer of this question

Answer (score 1):

sumitkm has right, all this conversion is unnecessary since at the end updateID is passing to param's NSString through stringWithFormat method. In addition to that I had to add to reply message prefix with name of user that I reply to, so example message would look like: "@MichalGumny my reply message". It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Prashanth,

The original MGTwitterEngine used an unsigned long as the tweet id. But the Tweet IDs have long gone past unsigned long id size. You'll need to change the tweet id to a NSString and pass it around as a NSString. Internally the value is posted as a part of URL so it's okay to pass it around as a string.

I posted the required changes [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4707048/mgtwitterengine-fav-a-tweet/).

I haven't tried reply to a tweet myself, I'll give it a shot and post here if things are different.

Comment: I did the change already but reply not being posted.. even nothing is happening not even a new tweet being created :(... Any ideas

Comment: Same Problem here, changed the parameter id to (NSString*) and it posts as regular tweet