# SA_OAuthTwitterEngine and MGTwitterEngine retweet doesn't works

Tags: objective-c, mgtwitterengine

I'm developing an iOS app with Twitter features.

To do that I'm using SA_OAuthTwitterEngine and MGTwitterEngine wrappers. I've followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2528741/how-to-do-a-retweet-on-an-iphone-twitter-app-mgtwitterengine) post.

I'm trying to retweet a tweet from the followed user timeline.

This is what I send/receive:

```
2012-04-12 18:34:00.291 Project[13605:207] INFO -> Twitter URL: https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/retweet/190459190869753856.xml
2012-04-12 18:34:00.292 Project[13605:207] INFO -> retweet response: 0AFF2EF9-6BCC-4B1E-B65A-02BD24A38C18
```

Here I pass to the API the id field of the selected tweet which I want to retweet. But after execute the method, the retweeted doesn't appears in the user timeline, where I'm getting the user tweets and tweets retweeted by user.

What I'm loosing here?

According with [this](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/post/statuses/retweet/:id) the request to the Twitter API is ok. And I've checked the app permissions setted in twitter and have all: read/write and direct messages.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4707048/mgtwitterengine-fav-a-tweet/) post.

The change that must be done is treat the updateID param as NSString instead of unsigned long.